# Outlook 2013 forward window vanishes when switching between windows

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have an recurring issue in outlook (which I've been able to reproduce). When I receive an email:

- I click the forward button
- I click the 'Pop-out' button
- I Address the email to someone
- I attach a file
- I switch to another window (to get some information from somewhere else)

When I attempt to return to my work-in-progress email, it has vanished. Not just the content or something. The whole window has disappeared.

**EDIT:** After about 30 minutes these emails turn up in my Drafts folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> after you attached a file before switching to another windows. Hopefully it will help.